# Change visible date format Angular 7 Saturn-datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

I uses Angular Saturn-datepicker.  `"saturn-datepicker": "7.2.1",`
I need to show just last two digits in a year, from `2020` to `20`.
Here is my template

```
<div
  class="create-request__select"
  (click)="setMinMaxInterval(); picker.open()"
>
  <input
    class="my-input"
    [satDatepicker]="picker"
    [min]="minDate"
    [max]="maxDate"
    (dateChange)="dateChange($event.value)"
    [value]="dateRange"
    readonly
  />
  <sat-datepicker #picker [rangeMode]="true"></sat-datepicker>
</div>
```

Here is my imports in app.module.js

```
import {
  DateAdapter,
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
  MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
  SatDatepickerModule,
  SatNativeDateModule
} from "saturn-datepicker";

     { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MyDateAdapter },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: "ru-RU" },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MyDateFormat },
```

Here is my change adapter and format

```
@Injectable()
export class MyDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return 1;
  }
}

export const MyDateFormat = {
  display: {
    dateInput: "DD.MMMM.YY",
    monthYearLabel: "MMMM YYYY",
    dateA11yLabel: "MM/DD/YYYY",
    monthYearA11yLabel: "MMMM YYYY"
  }
};
```

But same result.
Please help me.
[image]

Comment: This works on angular 7 as well[Angular 8 date format change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68629455/how-to-format-date-in-angular-8-saturn-datepicker):